# converting a pine script strategy to study (stop orders)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i would like to convert the pine script strategy below to study

```
//@version=5
strategy("Volty Expan Close Strategy", overlay=true)
length = input(5)
numATRs = input(0.75)
atrs = ta.sma(ta.tr, length)*numATRs

strategy.entry("VltClsLE", strategy.long, stop=close+atrs, comment = "VltClsLE")
strategy.entry("VltClsSE", strategy.short, stop=close-atrs, comment = "VltClsSE")
```

i have read through some documentation and questions asked here. unfortunately, i couldnt find any specific answer or example for converting "stop=close+atrs" this stop order to indicator.

highly appreciate if anyone can assist me on this please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to simulate the strategy variables and functions yourself.

For many of the variables you need to use the `var` keyword so their values are consistent.

You need to know your entry price, stop loss price and your position size.

So, you can do something like this:

```
var bool is_in_long_position = false
var float entry_price = na
var float stop_price = na

if (long_entry_condition and not is_in_long_position)
    entry_price := close
    stop_price := // calculate your stop price
    is_in_long_position := true

if (is_in_long_position)
    if (low <= stop_price)    // Your SL is hit
        entry_price := na
        stop_price := na
        is_in_long_position := na
```